# Grbl on Arduino Uno (Elegoo) with DM542 + nema24 stepper motor not working

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper-motor

i've already searched and tried for a quite depressing amount of hours, but am not able to solve this problem:

The parts are the following:
 - Elegoo Arduino Uno, on wich i flashed GRBL
 - 24v Power Supply (wich powers the stepper motor(s)
 - Nema24 3nm stepper motor
 - A DM542 Driver
 - bCNC (exe-build on win7 and win10)

Now, i connected one stepper-driver and stepper-motor as x-axis to the arduino.
The wiring is as following:
 - 5v from arduino to the three + Pins (ENA, DIR and PUL)
 - Pin 2 to PUL, Pin 5 to DIR, Pin 8 to ENA
 - 24V go to + and ground port of the driver, the 4 motor-wires are wired accordingly to the driver

I downloaded GRBL from Github and flashed it to the Arduino (i can run grbl-commands from the serial monitor inside the arduino ide, grbl is unlocked), connected everything and opened up bCNC, searched for the arduino on com-port, wich is shown correctly, and connected wich works fine (in the main screen "connected" shows up).
However when i try to move the x-axis under the control-panel in bcnc, nothing moves, on the screen the numbers change correctly and i get an ok in the logs, but the motor does not move a bit.
I double checked the wiring and tried to write a little program in arduino ide to move the stepper motor without grbl (deleted grbl, wrote a little program wich manually set the intervals ecc), without changing the wiring, that worked...
How can i debug this? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, that you connected the positive pins of ENA, DIR and PUL to 5V, I guess you use the common anode connection scheme from the DM542's [datasheet](http://www.sah.co.rs/media/sah/techdocs/dm542_manual.pdf) (the driver seems to have optocouplers for the inputs). That would mean the inputs are active low (a Pulse would be a transition from HIGH to LOW and then back to HIGH).

GRBL v1.1 has by default an active high pulse signal:

> By default, a step signal starts at normal-low and goes high upon a step pulse event. After a step pulse time set by $0, the pin resets to low, until the next step pulse event.

(from the [GRBL github wiki](https://github.com/gnea/grbl/wiki/Grbl-v1.1-Configuration)). I guess, this is the problem. Please try to set GRBL for inverting the pulse signal with `$2` (you may well find a corresponding setting inside bCNC.

Be sure, that GRBL is outputting the signals, that your driver is expecting in your connection scheme.

Comment: Hi, chrisl,
thanks for your response!
I'll try it and let you know if it worked ;-) And yes, i use a similar datasheet with the same wiring wich was delivered with the stepper motors =)

Comment: Hey chrisl, it worked!!! Thanks man!
I had to invert the ENA-Pin too, but now it works like a charm!
Now i need to figure out how to set the options when the arduino is connected to bcnc, but that's another story.

Thanks again!!